# itext split PDF into several PDF but get same size

Tags: java, pdf, split, itext

this is my code for split single PDF in a several PDF splitted by page:

```
public static String splitAndRenamePdf(InputStream file, String targetDir) {
        try {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file);
            int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
            for (int i=1; i <= n; i++) {
                Document document = new Document(reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(i)); //I tried with 1 too
                PdfCopy writer = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(targetDir+File.separatorChar+i+".pdf"));
                document.open();
                PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
                writer.addPage(page);
                document.close();
                writer.close();
            }
            return "from 01 to "+n;
        } catch (IOException | DocumentException exc) {
            System.out.println("splitAndRenamePdf Exception: "+exc.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

the content is right but the resulting n files are each the same size as the original.

Someone could help me? I could change library because I'm not legacy with iText.

Comment: I solved with reading this post: http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Resources-All-on-First-Page-td4660563.html#a4660597

Comment: Hi G.Dileo. Welcome to StackOverflow. Do you know that it is possible to answer your own question if you have found a solution? In that way you can help others who have the same problem. You can even accept it as the solution. If you do that you'll also get upvotes from the community. So answer your qestion, add the code which helped you and reference the original post from nabble...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write **the solution**...
I hope it could help someone.

```
private final static RenderListener nopListener = new RenderListener() {
        @Override
        public void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) { }

        @Override
        public void renderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo) { }

        @Override
        public void endTextBlock() { }

        @Override
        public void beginTextBlock() { }
    };

static class Do implements ContentOperator {
        public void invoke(PdfContentStreamProcessor processor, PdfLiteral operator, ArrayList<PdfObject> operands) {
            PdfName xobjectName = (PdfName)operands.get(0);
            names.add(xobjectName);
        }

        final List<PdfName> names = new ArrayList<>();
    }

private static void fixPdfReader(PdfReader reader) throws IOException {
        PdfContentStreamProcessor processor = new PdfContentStreamProcessor(nopListener);
        Do doOp = new Do();
        processor.registerContentOperator("Do", doOp);
        int totPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        for (int page = 1; page <= totPages; page++) {
            PdfDictionary resources = reader.getPageResources(page);
            if (resources == null) {
                System.out.printf("!!! page %d has no resources\n", page);
                continue;
            }
            doOp.names.clear();
            processor.processContent(ContentByteUtils.getContentBytesForPage(reader, page), resources);
            PdfDictionary newResources = new PdfDictionary();
            newResources.putAll(resources);
            PdfDictionary xobjects = newResources.getAsDict(PdfName.XOBJECT);
            PdfDictionary newXobjects = new PdfDictionary();
            for (PdfName key: doOp.names) {
                newXobjects.put(key, xobjects.get(key));
            }
            newResources.put(PdfName.XOBJECT, newXobjects);
            reader.getPageN(page).put(PdfName.RESOURCES, newResources);
        }
        reader.removeUnusedObjects();
    }

public static String fixAndSplitPDF(InputStream inputStream, String targetDir) {
        try {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputStream);
            fixPdfReader(reader);
            //this method is in the question!
            return splitAndRenamePdf(reader, targetDir);
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            //LOG Exception...
            return null;
        }
    }
```